# How can I trigger a large block of JavaScript code in IE despite the URL's 2000 character limit?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, bookmarklet

I'm working on a project where I use JavaScript to click on web elements based on conditions (e.g., based on what elements exist on the page, what values are stored in variables, etc.). We're trying to reduce the amount of repetitive actions in browser-based clerical work.

My current solution is to turn the JavaScript code into a bookmarklet so the user can click on the bookmark to run the script. However, my code exceeds 2000 characters (which is greater that the URL character limit), so I now need to store it in two separate bookmarklets (and soon to be three).

Our company's internal platform is only working on IE11 so moving to Firefox/Chrome is out of the question.

Comment: browser extension is so much easier.

Comment: @epascarello can I store JavaScript code in a browser extension in IE11? May I ask how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You could introduce external JavaScript codes into bookmarklets to avoid the url length limit. You could write your JavaScript function in a js file and host the file in a url, then introduce the js file like this:

```
javascript:(function(){
       var script=document.createElement('script');
　　　　script.setAttribute('src', 'http://path/to/external/file.js');
　　　　document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
})();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Is it possible to store the JavaScript file locally? Like on a shared drive on the LAN?